# Evaluate JSP expression and use it to build a HTML URL

Tags: java, html, jsp

In my JSP I am displaying an expression in a table. This expression, e.g. r.getName() I want to be hyperlinked, so that I can route the query elsewhere.

```
<tr>
 <td><%=r.getName()%></td>
</tr>
```

The idea being when I click on the link pointed to by r.getName() it will route me to google.com or some other link.

How can I accomplish this? I've been playing around a bit but dont quite have the answer yet. In HTML here's a little of what I think it might look like:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="<%=r.getName()%>"</a>Link to Google</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post a possible value of `r.getName`? Also, does it have to be in scriptlet or you can use EL and JSTL?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A possible value of r.getName() could be "myproject.zip". Preferably in scriptlet - although I'd be curious as to what the alternatives are.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is incorrect, it should be

```
<a href="<%=r.getName()%>">Link to Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your back end you can set the URL in a numerous ways.

If you are using servlets and JSPs only without any other libraries you can add the name to the request and call it from the JSP like below :

```
 <a href="<c:out value='${requestScope.nameOfTheRequestParam}'/>">
 Link to Google</a>
```

Or you can use a custom tag etc. Really there's no one way of doing this.

Comment: You probably mean `<c:url>` instead of `<c:out>` since it would be an URL.

Comment: I was just being generic since I wasn't sure if the getName will provide an actual URL. But yes if it does then it's better suited for this.